# unable to create docker container on windows VM, GCP

Tags: windows, docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting the below issue
`67ca2e6ea573a4e3eb0843b2c7470c26f170528a15e423b4b131c00fa23 encountered an error during CreateContainer:
ndows system call: Element not found. (0x490) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"42fb367ca2e6e
2c7470c26f170528a15e423b4b131c00fa23","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"VolumePath":"\\?\Volume{52225f
46-00155d20b364}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilte
ea573a4e3eb0843b2c7470c26f170528a15e423b4b131c00fa23","Layers":[{"ID":"f58d5d31-bf26-57f0-a0ef-c826de66f9
\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\a0ead5582d1eadd37c0629d34936e2ec93f9594bd2740f9244481088df738b0b"},{
f525-57f0-912a-668391cb4d95","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\371369a0885812ef094658377937
b51bf6d59472a50c088d6"},{"ID":"1ab4ed85-2f0b-52ec-bd73-b24fef768054","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\win
a9962919b2b604a94d414393fdcb73f5c04539f819e896e870ee81b844b1b"},{"ID":"286c76b4-45ad-561d-83f7-224c0a84d7
\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\9647a3b62bffb27464188dc7859e82b2a373737462891cf711edc18d58054a43"},{
2bb2-5c34-bd4b-38f992457749","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\00d0db95b9df22d3167096cef32c
f0b5f0f0b0992dbf09bf6"},{"ID":"fa36e2c8-07ba-5f2a-a43b-a3ccb1023b46","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\win
5f0e4abdc9fbe8a5ad0a94cf0fd92b329f1b8d2a65d0b8e5547c18c9def64"},{"ID":"a9d1658d-0a19-50ca-a4d5-afbfc93fae
\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\645c6553c4b7ddb03f572f5872040c5df180daca938a4a05d616724d58217abd"},{
c953-5398-a203-08225685147d","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\4e6fbe4ec92a4809054beaa92071
c130c736f07181762d748"},{"ID":"187257dd-6219-558d-9873-f42219c6c2ef","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\win
78d0243c72052c330026dcc04fd7c040e708003a821bf94a6a3f289c4f27b"}],"HostName":"b3e4c8818481","MappedDirecto
tition":false,"EndpointList":["c563efff-bfeb-4cd2-b4b5-0c018aad913a"],"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqualified`

hack for the above issue is: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32595#issuecomment-295347128

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked issue, this is a known issue with the windows image running on GCP: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32595#issuecomment-295310855

Comment: This is not a known issue. This was introduced in the new windows update that was rolled out recently.......

Comment: Known issue to me means that it's been reported and acknowledged in the github issue list, I'm not implying a time reference. This is in contrast to being a problem with how you are running your code.

Comment: I have posted the issue here so that people can get benefited from the hack...... On github I was one of the persons who raised the issue